# I have finished rendering my animation into PNG files, how do I edit?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I don't know how to make all the PNGs into one seamless short, via iMovie/Filmora

Comment: You can use Blender's Video Sequence Editor to import the image sequence, perform editing and export as a video file. There is no need for using another software, unless you require a specific feature that Blender doesn't offer.

Answer (score -1):

I use Hitfilm Express ( free ) and Openshot video editor ( also free ); both can import the set of .png's as an image sequence.

it is best to put them in a separate directory with only the image sequence as you need to select the directory.

Comment: Why don't you use Blender?